# Update JSON object via functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
var objList = [
    {name: 'John', salary: 2000000}, {name: 'Adam', salary: 190000},
    {name: 'Sally', salary: 300000}
]
```

Filter the objects with salary > 195000 and return objects with just name and no salary. (Use functional Programming)

Approach:

```
function filter(objList){
var temp = [];
objList.filter(function(value, index){
     return value.salary > 195000;
}).forEach(function(value, index){
      temp.push(name: value.name);
});

return temp;
}
```

How can we do the same without temp array (functional programming).

Comment: Array#map is one way - also your push argument is invalid anyway, so that code doesn't run at all ... `let filter = objList => objList.filter(value => value.salary > 195000).map(value =>({name: value.name}));
`

Comment: if you're studying "functional programming", by which you seem to mainly mean the ES5 array methods which take functions as parameters, then just read the relevant pages such as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or many others, and you'll find the method(s) you need.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by functional programming.

Are you hoping to avoid mutations, or remove side effects, or use methods that accept higher order functions?

You can certainly remove the need for the temporary array by using `.map` instead.

```
objList
  .filter(person => person.salary > 195000)
  .map(person => person.name)
```

Or you could write your own recursive solution.

```
function getHighEarners([head, ...tail]) {
  if (!head) return [];
  if (head.salary > 195000) return [head.name, ...getHighEarners(tail)];
  return getHighEarners(tail);
}
```

This approach also lends itself to an explicitly curried solution.

```
function getEarnersByThreshold(salary) {
  return function getHighEarners([head, ...tail]) {
    if (!head) return [];
    if (head.salary > salary) return [head.name, ...getHighEarners(tail)];
    return getHighEarners(tail);
  }
}
```

Equally, you could use `.reduce`, but I think it makes the intention less clear.

```
objList.reduce(
  (names, person) => (person.salary > 195000)
     ? [...names, person.name]
     : names,
  []
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
objList
  .filter(({salary}) => salary > 195000)
  .map   (({name})   => ({name}))
```

Use `filter` to pull out only the objects with a `salary` greater than 1950.. Then use `map` on the results to map the array of objects including `salary` into an array of objects containing only `name`.

We use "parameter destructuring" (the `({salary}) =>` and `({name}) =>` syntax) to pull out the properties we are interested in right in the parameter list.